# Printing JTables without formatting of the original component

Tags: java, jtable

I'm writing an application which utilises tables which can be printed if the user so desires and I wish to print a JTable filled with data, except I haven't been able to find an option to remove the formatting; the printed tables looks like it does in the GUI (based on the system theme) which is making the table less readable and using excess ink.

I wish to print the same data with clear formatting. Is there a way to do this straight from a JTable or is my best option simply to print to a file and have the use printer from there. Currently it functions through a viewer which gives the user some options for printing, and then it goes to the system's printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1.5, "Simple new [`print()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) methods allow for quick and easy addition of printing support to your application."